# Bash 'ls' does not accept * wildcard

Tags: bash, wildcard, ls

I find it strange that when I use the `*` wildcard , `ls` sometimes takes it literally. Here's the actual case: I have the following folder structure:
This is the output of `ls`

```
00  02  04  06  08  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24  26  28  30  32  34  36  38  40  42  44  46  48  99       Codes                    X12
01  03  05  07  09  11  13  15  17  19  21  23  25  27  29  31  33  35  37  39  41  43  45  47  98  ALL_RAW  Implemented_NN_Model.h5
```

Each of the numbered folders (00 to 99) contains the following files:

```
00_Binarized_Cutoff_0.99_.tif  00_dot_img_model.png  00_Final_Loc.tif  00_Raw_Prediction.tif  Implemented_NN_Model.h5
```

I want to extract all the `*_Final_Loc.tif` files from these folders.
Hence I tried this:
`ls -R *Final*tif`, and this:  `ls *Final*tif`.
I get the same output in both cases:

```
ls: cannot access '*Final*tif': No such file or directory
```

I am just curious to know why `ls` takes the `*` literally, and what is the correct way?
A side information, I was able to do this task, but when I used this:

```
ls  [0-9][0-9]/*Final*tif
```

i.e.,

```
for file in `ls  [0-9][0-9]/*Final*tif` ; do cp ${file} ../ALL_Final_Loc/ ; done
```

And this is strange too, since I don't find a logical explanation for why it should work here.

Comment: The glob is expand by the shell, with the results being passed as arguments to `ls`. You seem to be expecting `ls` itself to match the pattern against the results of `ls -R`.

Comment: `ls  **/*Final*tif` (might require a `shopt -s globstar` first)

Comment: @chepner  What should be the correct way then? Sorry, if I sound naive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the directory as well like so:
`ls */*Final*tif`

Unfortunately, `ls -R` doesn't work with wildcards in a particularly useful way so for a case where there are multiple directory levels you could use `find`, like so:
`find . -name '*Final*tif'`

Answer (score 2):

Glob expansion is done by the shell. When you run `ls *Final*tif` bash will find files which match the pattern `*Final*tif` and paste their names to the command. As there are no files with names like that in the current directory, the expansion fails and `ls` now receives a literal `*Final*tif` as parameter which obviously doesn't exist and produces the error

```
ls: cannot access '*Final*tif': No such file or directory
```

Same to `ls -R *Final*tif`. To find files like that use `find`:

```
find -name "*Final*tif"
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great way too!

Answer (score 2):

For [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion), if there are no files that match the pattern, the default behaviour is that the pattern then remains in the command as a literal string. (The [shell options](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) `nullglob` and `failglob` can control this behaviour)

The reason why the pattern matches no files is because there are no directory separators in it. You want

```sh
echo */*Final*tif
```

or

```sh
find . -name '*Final*tif' -ls
```