# wildcard in variable for ls + bash

Tags: bash

why does the wild card at the end not work when I put it in a variable and then do an ls with that variable?
I am sure there is something obvious, but can't see it at the minute.

```
>qq="/home/sims/data/202301*/Config/eNB/external-eutran-cell-fdd-logic*"
>ls "$qq"
ls: cannot access /home/sims/data/202301*/Config/eNB/external-eutran-cell-fdd-logic*: No such file or directory

> ls -l /home/sims/data/202301*/Config/eNB/external-eutran-cell-fdd-logic*
-rw-r--r--. 1 sims sims 29693478 Jan  1 07:51 /home/sims/data/20230101/Config/eNB/external-eutran-cell-fdd-logic.csv

> 
> ls "$qq"
ls: cannot access /home/sims/data/202301*/Config/eNB/external-eutran-cell-fdd-logic*: No such file or directory
> echo "$qq"
/home/sims/data/202301*/Config/eNB/external-eutran-cell-fdd-logic*
```

related
[Bash 'ls' does not accept * wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71710623/bash-ls-does-not-accept-wildcard)

Comment: The double quotes on `"$qq"` prevent the shell from expanding the `*`.

Comment: The question you have linked has perfectly good explanations about why `ls "/some/path/file*"` won't work (IMO). The clue is that the `*` is still visible in the error message.